# RPi.GPIO problems on PI 4b

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, gpiozero

"This module can only be run on a Raspberry Pi" error when using RPi.GPIO on Raspberry Pi 4b.

This error was caused by the default RPi.GPIO version installed with:

```
python3 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

This command seems to install a version which is incompatible with PI 4b (Version 0.5.0).
You can fix this error by typing:

```
python3 -m pip install RPi.GPIO==0.7.0
```

This was on a clean installation of Python3 and Raspbian using only the recommended installation commands found online.

I had already run apt-get update and apt-get upgrade and couldn't find any answers containing this solution after some searching around.
Hopefully, this will save some time for somebody else.

Let me know if I missed the solution elsewhere or if I created this problem somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with the above.

```
python3 -m pip install RPi.GPIO
```

There may be a more up to date version by the time you read this.